# Using Javascript functions in a separate HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, parameter-passing, ejs

I know it might seem like a dumb question but even with all the examples i have looked through i can not get it too work. 
I have the following code in my Javascript file

server.js

```
  // Google Maps Locaton 
  googleMapsClient.geocode({
    address: city
  }, function(err, response) {
    if (!err) {
      basicLocation = response.json.results[0].formatted_address;
      console.log(basicLocation);
    }
  });

});

function getBasicLocation() {   // Able to grab location from index.ejs file 
  return basicLocation;
}
```

in my HTML im trying to update text as the location changes. My html code looks like this

index.ejs

```
<script src="../server.js">
    </script>
      <h3>
        <script> getBasicLocation() </script> Location
      </h3>
```

The way my files are set up in the directory is like

```
- app 
   - views 
     - index.ejs
   - server.js
```

How do i get the getBasicLocation() to talk to my index.ejs file so that it updates the text?

Comment: Look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49343185/script-wont-run-from-ejs-file-in-nodejs-application), it might help you

Comment: Try making basicLocation a global variable

Answer (score 0):

Below steps should work -

1. Import server.js - You are doing this
2. create HTML node where you want location 
   e.g div id="location"
3. create script tag with below content

   ```
           let lc = getBasicLocation();
   document.getElementById("location").innerHTML = lc;
   ```

JQuery can further simplify your node selection code